# TypeError from MultinomialNB: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I am trying to compare the performance of Multinomial, Binomial and Bernoulli classifiers but I am having an error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'

The code below is til `MultinomialNB`.

```
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)

#print(documents[1])

all_words = []

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def look_for_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for x in word_features:
        features[x] = {x in words}
    return features

#feature set will be finding features and category
featuresets = [(look_for_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

training_set = featuresets[:1400]
testing_set = featuresets[1400:]

#Multinomial
MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print ("Accuracy: ", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier,testing_set))*100)
```

The error seems to be in `MNB_classifier.train(training_set)`. 
The error in this code is similar to error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814086/naive-base-classifier-of-nltk-giving-unhashable-type-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change...

```
features[x] = {x in words}
```

to...

```
features[x] = x in words
```

The first line creates a list `featuresets` of pairs `(word, {True})` or `(word, {False})`, i.e. the second element is a `set`. `SklearnClassifier` does not expect this as a label.

---

The code looks very much like one from ["Creating a module for Sentiment Analysis with NLTK"](https://pythonprogramming.net/sentiment-analysis-module-nltk-tutorial/). The author is using a tuple `(x in words)` there, but it's no different from just `x in words`.